# Determine coordinates for an object at a specific distance and angle from a point

Tags: math, rotation, geometry, 2d, coordinates

In a 2d space, I have an object of coordinates x1 and y1 and it is facing a specific direction , we'll call it "viewer". At start, the angle that measures the object rotation is 0, so the object starts  always facing the same way. The angle is measured by a variable called yrot.

let D be the distance from the object determined by  sqrt ((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2), consider this distance known.

Now, knowing the viewer coordinates, the D distance and the yrot angle I want to determine the coordinates x2, y2 of the object that is at distance D from the viewer object's face.

To clarify this I will add a simple matrix to explain what I want:

Z 0 0

0 0 0

0 0 V

V is the viewer, V is facing towards Z. I am only interested if there is an object in front of V(at the specific distance). In other words, suppose Z is at distance D(known) from V, I am only interested if Z is an object, nothing else.

I believe the needed coordinates are x2 = x1 (+/-) d* sin yrot;  y2 =  y1 (+/-) d*cos yrot;
I am not sure if this is the correct formula and it doesn't seem to be working. I am also unsure abut the signum of the second operand.

If anything is unclear, please leave comments and I will do my best to answer as fast as possible.

Thank you!

Later edit:
            || <- where is viewer oriented, yrot = 0; 
            [] <- viewer

```
        = [] <- viewer yrot = 90 degrees.
```

This should clarify what yrot is. Also, the object can rotate as much as I want to ( > 2 PI) and it can rotate both clock-wise and counter clock wise.

Charles Bretana's answer seems almost correct, I'm not sure if it covers overrotating(rotating > 360 degrees) and rotating in different directions.

Comment: I'm having a hard time to understand the question. Could you provide any visual on what you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given a point A (ax, ay), the coordinates of the point B (bx, by) which is a distance d from A in the direction represented by angle t (where `t: - pi < t < + pi` and is measured counter clockwise from the positive x direction), would be:

```
 bx = ax + d*cos(t)
 by = ay + d*sin(t)
```

I'm not exactly sure if this approach matches your question, as It is not clear from your question what angle `yrot` represents.  But if you determine `yrot` as simply the angle between the viewer's line of sight to the point B with the positive X-Axis, the above should work.

To cover overrotating, just take the yRot and subtract 2*Pi until the result is between - Pi and +Pi

Comment: I  believe your answer is what I am looking forward, to  better understand what yrot is and how it works I will edit my question.