# Distance calculating algorithm for an app

Tags: java, geometry

I'm trying to calculate the distance for a third grader's geometry game app I'm developing. The basic idea is that the user inputs the directions using directions and how long he wants to go in each direction.( eg input: Right (radians) , travel a metres, left (radians), travel b metres).

So, now my app will find out if the user can get back to the starting point and how far he is away from home.

So far, I have been able to proceed with this logic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895237/determine-coordinates-for-an-object-at-a-specific-distance-and-angle-from-a-poin). I would like to know if there are other ways to do this? thanks!

Comment: Can't you just add the distances up? Or are you trying to find your displacement from initial starting point?

Comment: Sorry but how will adding the distances up help me? the user will be travelling in a triangle formation.

Comment: I'm confused - how far have you got with this? You say you are proceeding with logic found in another question - does that logic work for you?

Comment: So you're looking to find how far away from your starting point? That's the displacement.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the displacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using third grade geometry fittingly.

When you use the commands you listed, you are creating a vector. If you store `dir`, `x`, and `y` you can use simple sin and cosin to figure out your ending location.

```
dir+=rad
x+=cosin(dir)
y+=sin(dir)
```

If you have saved your start location, you can use Pythagorean Theorem to figure out the displacement from home!

```
public double distance (int x, int y){
    int xdist = x-startx;
    int ydist = y-starty;

    int squarex = xdist*xdist
    int squarey = ydist*ydist

    return Math.sqrt((double)(squarex+squarey));
}
```